# I need to extract a part of the url in an iframe

Tags: php, iframe

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/322332324?byline=0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I need to get extract the numbers from the src.. I need to get 322332324. no matter how many digits there are.

This code will get the src but how do I get just the number

preg_match('/src="([^"]+)"/', $iframe_string, $match);
$url = $match[1];

Comment: Helps if there are any knowns that will not change. Are there any? Can you list them out?

Comment: You could use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the path, explode it on `/` and take the last element.

Comment: this is always the same "src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/"

Comment: Since you removed the comment for my answer saying that it helped (and the fact that you haven't accepted it), does that mean that it didn't work for you? If not, please let me know what happens.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it worked !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the digits always are the last part of the URL, you could do it like this:

**Alternative 1**

```
$url = 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/322332324?byline=0';

// Extract the path from the URL
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

// Explode the path on / to get the different fragments
$fragments = explode('/', $path);

// Now simply take the last part of the fragemnts
$numbers = end($fragments);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/TI1El

**Alternative 2**

If you want less code, you can skip the explode part and just substr() and strrpos(). Less code but less verbose:

```
$url = 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/322332324?byline=0';

// Get the path from the URL
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

// Get the everything after the last slash
$numbers = substr($path, strrpos($path, '/') + 1);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/aRjfc

Comment: @IsmailMathkour - If it solved your issue, please feel free to accept the answer.